# Configure gsutil s3 in Google Cloud SDK Docker

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

I have Google Cloud SDK docker configured and running on my windows machine after following this.
https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/

I'm trying to run this command to list a s3 bucket

```
docker run --rm -ti --volumes-from gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk gsutil ls s3://bucketname
```

Authentication fails due to not setting the AWS keys. I presume from `.boto` file not having `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` set. I can't seem to figure out how to set those variables.

I tried to run this to generate a `.boto` file but the bucket was shared with me and I don't have access keys.

```
docker run --rm -ti --volumes-from gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk gsutil config -a
```

Am I missing something or is there any other way to set these AWS credentials? Maybe with `gcloud config set`?

Here is the error log

```
ERROR 1202 03:16:07.326810 utils.py] Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1324, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1260, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1306, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1255, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1030, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 970, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 942, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/utils.py", line 220, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1352, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1326, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
ERROR 1202 03:16:07.328018 utils.py] Unable to read instance data, giving up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil", line 21, in <module>
    gsutil.RunMain()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil.py", line 122, in RunMain
    sys.exit(gslib.__main__.main())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 444, in main
    user_project=user_project)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 783, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
    _HandleUnknownFailure(e)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 640, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
    user_project=user_project)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command_runner.py", line 412, in RunNamedCommand
    return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/ls.py", line 683, in RunCommand
    listing_helper.ExpandUrlAndPrint(storage_url))
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/ls_helper.py", line 372, in ExpandUrlAndPrint
    print_initial_newline=False)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/ls_helper.py", line 449, in _RecurseExpandUrlAndPrint
    bucket_listing_fields=self.bucket_listing_fields):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/wildcard_iterator.py", line 540, in IterAll
    expand_top_level_buckets=expand_top_level_buckets):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/wildcard_iterator.py", line 174, in __iter__
    fields=bucket_listing_fields):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/boto_translation.py", line 447, in ListObjects
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/storage_uri.py", line 166, in list_bucket
    bucket = self.get_bucket(headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/storage_uri.py", line 181, in get_bucket
    conn = self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/storage_uri.py", line 117, in connect
    **connection_args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/s3/connection.py", line 205, in __init__
    validate_certs=validate_certs, profile_name=profile_name)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/connection.py", line 573, in __init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/vendored/boto/boto/auth.py", line 1032, in get_auth_handler
    'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['S3HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error is related to missing aws secrets? What is the exact error log? Enter to the container with docker exec... and try to configure the aws authentication. Usually is the `aws configure`. If it works, you just need to pass the credentials using env with docker

Comment: Are you sure that the error is related to missing aws secrets? What is the exact error log? Enter to the container with docker exec... and try to configure the aws authentication. Usually is the `aws configure`. If it works, you just need to pass the credentials using env with docker

Comment: `aws` is not part of the image, however i did find a `.boto`  file in `cat root/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/...../.boto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the `.boto` file in the legacy config and got this to work.

```
docker restart gcloud-config
docker exec -u 0 -it <container-id-here>/bin/bash
apt-get install nano
nano root/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/***/.boto
```

add under `[Credentials]`

```
aws_access_key_id = ***
aws_secret_access_key = ***
```

enjoy

```
docker run --rm -ti --volumes-from gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk gsutil ls s3://bucketname
```